# UI parallelism between Swift and Android

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, android-layout

I'm trying to develop and Android app which is based on the UI of this iOS app. I'd like to reproduce two things:

1. As you can see, there are three buttons on the bottom of the app and by clicking on them you can move between the screens without refreshing the whole activity. Are there similar views I can use in Android to reproduce it?
2. On the activity of the screen, there is a list of film. I would thinking to reproduce it by creating a listview. Do you are there better alternatives?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You could use a `BottomNavigationView` to recreate this style of navigation. You can add the `BottomNavigationView` to your `Activity` and then use individual `Fragment`s for the inner views i.e. Home, Search and More.
2. `ListView` would be alright for this or you could use a `RecyclerView` with a `LinearLayoutManager`. `RecyclerView` is a bit more flexible than `ListView` as you could change the LayoutManager for a `GridLayoutManager` if you wanted on larger devices.

I'd also recommend checking out https://material.io/components/ where you can see what sort of design guidance Google give for their Material design system.